# Form expires and shows the result after the time is up

Tags: php, html, timer, countdown

I am a beginner in PHP. So I am working on a small task in which I want to make a form in which there are MCQS and there is a countdown timer above it of 10 minutes. When the count down timer is up the form should expire and should show the result automatically.
I have made the form as coded below but I don't know what to do so that I can add timer in this code so that the form expires and shows the result of the right selected answers.

```html
<html>

    <head>

        <title>PHP Quiz</title>

        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page-wrap">

            <h1>Final Quiz for Lip building</h1>

            <form action="quiz.php"  method="post" id="quiz">

                <ol>

                    <li>

                        <h3>CSS Stands for...</h3>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" />
                            <label for="question-1-answers-A">A) Computer Styled Sections </label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-B" value="B" />
                            <label for="question-1-answers-B">B) Cascading Style Sheets</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-C" value="C" />
                            <label for="question-1-answers-C">C) Crazy Solid Shapes</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-D" value="D" />
                            <label for="question-1-answers-D">D) None of the above</label>
                        </div>

                    </li>

                    <li>

                        <h3>Internet Explorer 6 was released in...</h3>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-A" value="A" />
                            <label for="question-2-answers-A">A) 2001</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-B" value="B" />
                            <label for="question-2-answers-B">B) 1998</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-C" value="C" />
                            <label for="question-2-answers-C">C) 2006</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-2-answers" id="question-2-answers-D" value="D" />
                            <label for="question-2-answers-D">D) 2003</label>
                        </div>

                    </li>

                    <li>

                        <h3>SEO Stand for...</h3>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-A" value="A" />
                            <label for="question-3-answers-A">A) Secret Enterprise Organizations</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-B" value="B" />
                            <label for="question-3-answers-B">B) Special Endowment Opportunity</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-C" value="C" />
                            <label for="question-3-answers-C">C) Search Engine Optimization</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="question-3-answers" id="question-3-answers-D" value="D" />
                            <label for="question-3-answers-D">D) Seals End Olives</label>
                        </div>

                    </li>


                </ol>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />

            </form>

        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: if someone submits the form before the timer is up, should they also see the results / right answers?  if so, you can create a timer in javascript which submits the form when it expires.  quiz.php would have the php code that checks the answers and displays results.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Answer (score 1):

You need JavaScript for such behavior, let's say you use the following JS:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.forms['form_name'].submit();
}, 2000);
```

`form_name` should be the name of your form. i.e

```
<form name = "form_name" ... >
</form>
```

This will delay the post in milliseconds (2 seconds) and then it should take you to another page where you can show the correct answers.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2edajoq/)

Comment: i still didn't get it exactly...can u show its demo on an online code editor like JS FIDDLE...as it will help me in getting your point clearly

Comment: @WasiXam I have added the fiddle, what is confusing you? What this function does is that it submits the form after the specified time and takes to to your `action = "quiz.php"` page. The rest is up to you.

Comment: ok thanks
one thing i want to know... is it possible to do this work task without javascript ?

Comment: @WasiXam I see you're trying to run away from JS. Why so? and Sadly no. Is there anything that you do not understand here? :)

Comment: i see..yes @HawasKaPujaari i want to also show the count down timer on this page so that i can watch and know how many hours,minutes and seconds are left :)

Comment: @WasiXam my laptop died :3 I will edit my answer soon as I can.

Comment: sure... i will be waiting for that

Comment: @WasiXam this should help you: http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/stopwatch.php and even this http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?234454-simple-javascript-countdown